# Giving link to the image in a array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a trouble giving link to the image in a array.

```
$sponsors = array(

array('id-1','tier1','app','http://www.google.com/'),
```

Here is the loop across the array, where

```
<?php
  foreach($sponsors as $company)
  {
    echo'
    <li data-id="'.$company[0].'" data-type="'.$company[1].'" style="">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/sustainability/assets/images/members/'.
          $company[1].'-'.$company[2].
          '.jpg" alt="More about '.$company[2].'" />
        <a href="#"></a>  
    </li>';
  }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your definition of `$sponsors` appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Also can you include the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to build an associative array?

```
array('id' => 'id-1','data-type' => 'tier1', 'key' => 'app', 'link' => 'http://www.google.com/'),
//......etc etc
```

Allowing you to loop through it and print it out as you'd like?

```
<?php
  foreach($sponsors as $company)
  {
    echo'
    <li data-id="'.$company['id'].'" data-type="'.$company['data-type'].'" style="">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/sustainability/assets/images/members/'.
          $company['data-type'].'-'.$company['key'].
          '.jpg" alt="More about '.$company['key'].'" />
        <a href="#"></a>  
    </li>';
  }

?>
```

<sup>*Note: I don't know what your `key` is called? So you'll want to change that to whatever it is? probably `product` right?*</sup>

Comment: I figured. I used .$company['3'] at href and got the link working.